# How to get lines between two patterns

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file like this:

> a sth1
>   a sth2
>   b sth3
>   b sth4
>   c sth5
>   c sth6
>   c sth6
>   d sth8
>   d sth9
>   d sth10
>   X sth10
>   X sth11

and I woul'd like to recive all lines between first line starting with `b` and last line starting with `d`:

> b sth3
>   b sth4
>   c sth5
>   c sth6
>   c sth6
>   d sth8
>   d sth9
>   d sth10

I have a sed command `sed -n /"b"/,/"d"/p final.txt` but the output is:

> b sth3
>   b sth4
>   c sth5
>   c sth6
>   c sth6
>   d sth8

My question is how to modify sed command to get expected result ?

**Im sorry for beeing not precise. I should ask about this:**

I have a file like this:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:11:21:01 +0200] STH1
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:11:21:01 +0200] STH2
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:11:21:01 +0200] STH3
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH4
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH5
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH6
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH7
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH8
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH9
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH10
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:14:21:01 +0200] STH11
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:14:21:01 +0200] STH12
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:15:21:01 +0200] STH13
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:15:21:01 +0200] STH14

and I want extract content between first line containing `$startDate="04/Jun/2014:12:21:01"` and last line containing `$endDate="04/Jun/2014:13:21:01"`. The result should be:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH4
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH5
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH6
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH7
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH8
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH9
>   127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH10

`$startDate` and `$endDate` are variables in BASH script. I really apologise for my last post where I asked not precise question...

Comment: is the file already sorted?

Comment: Actually I use a command `sed -n /"$startDate"/,/"$endDate"/p "final.txt" > output.txt` where `$startDate` and `$endDate` are BASH variables...

Comment: Yes, file is sorted by the first column. How to deal with sed in case of using bash variables as parameter as abpove ?

Comment: adapt your post and specify that first letter are in fact date (and give the format or better some real sample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is unsorted, then it is necessary to loop twice: first to know the lines to print and then to print them:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {if (/^b/ && !b) {b=NR} if (/^d/) {d=NR}; next} (FNR>=b && FNR<=d)' file file
b sth3
b sth4
c sth5
c sth6
c sth6
d sth8
d sth9
d sth10
```

As per comments, if you want to define the `b` and `d` as a parameter you can use:

```
-v start="your_start_date"
-v end="your_end_date"
```

See an example with current data:

```
$ awk -v start="b" -v end="d" 'FNR==NR {if ($1 == start && !b) {b=NR} if ($1 == end) {d=NR}; next} (FNR>=b && FNR<=d)' file file
b sth3
b sth4
c sth5
c sth6
c sth6
d sth8
d sth9
d sth10
```

---

Based on your last update:

```
$ startDate="04/Jun/2014:12:21:01"
$ endDate="04/Jun/2014:13:21:01"

$ awk -v start="$startDate" -v end="$endDate" 'FNR==NR {if ($0 ~ start && !b) {b=NR} if ($0 ~ end) {d=NR}; next} (FNR>=b && FNR<=d)' file file
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH4
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH5
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH6
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:12:21:01 +0200] STH7
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH8
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH9
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2014:13:21:01 +0200] STH10
```

Comment: Thx, but I would like to use this command in script whit parameters `$startDate` and `$endDate` to recive content between first line containing string `$startDate` and last line containing `$endDate`.

Comment: There is one more problem: `$startDate` and `$endDate` containing / for example: `05/Jun/2014:03:59:42`

Comment: Please update your question with a more clear sample input and desired output. Note also that other people is trying to answer your question and are not aware of what you comment here.

Answer (score 4):

### an awk one-liner

if your file is already sorted by the 1st column (the `a, b, c...`), this works for your example:

```
awk '$1>="b"&&$1<="d"' file
```

the `"b"` and  `"d"` here could be other string, like `abc` and `zzz` as long as the file was sorted, it should work.

### add a sed one-liner:

based on your example, this sed line worked here:

```
sed  -n '/^b/,/^d/{/^[^d]/p};/^d/p' file
```

Comment: for sed, you assume there are line with starting b and starting d, if one is missing, nothing will be printed (sample give both so ok in this case)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I think that is what OP wants, or I misunderstood...?

Comment: sure, but if there is no line with one of the 2 "edge", nothing will be printed, and that is not what is certainly expected. That's why i write "assuming" that i thing should be true most of the time but due to the generic sample it's not always the case and no print at all is not the request as i understand (maybe i wrong and pattern are only one existing in lines).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can do it in `awk`:

```
awk '/^b/{p=1} /^d/{p=2} p==2 && substr($1, 1, 1) != "d" {exit} p' file
b sth3
b sth4
c sth5
c sth6
c sth6
d sth8
d sth9
d sth10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  `awk`

```
awk '/^b/ {f=1} /^d/ {g=1} g && !/^d/ {f=0} f' file
b sth3
b sth4
c sth5
c sth6
c sth6
d sth8
d sth9
d sth10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sed command to get the expected result.

```
 $ sed -n '/^b/,/^d/{p;d};/^d/p' `input_filename`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `grep`:

```
grep "^[b-d]" file
```

Comment: If you see `OP`s comment in other post, `b` and  `d` are date, so this will fail.

Comment: @Jotne Oh, ok, thank you. I hate reading through loads of comments to see what the question really is - it would be much better if OPs updated their questions to show what they are really asking :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^b/p;/^c/p;/^d/p' YourFile
```

assuming it is sort like your sample. take care of missing line with `b` or `d`